# logrotate: What means the message "log has been already rotated"

Tags: linux, logrotate

If I run logrotate I get `log does not need rotating (log has been already rotated)` and the log file is not rotated. Why that?

My log rotate conf:

```
/var/log/capp/*.log {
    missingok
    rotate 90
    daily
    notifempty
    compress
    delaycompress
}
```

Before I run logrotate I remove the line

```
"/var/log/capp/server.log" 2019-4-1-7:0:0
```

from file `/var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status`

logrotate output:

```
/> logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.d/capp 
reading config file /etc/logrotate.d/capp
Allocating hash table for state file, size 15360 B

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /var/log/capp/*.log  after 1 days (90 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/capp/server.log
  log does not need rotating (log has been already rotated)
```

and the log file is not rotated:

```
/> ls -la  /var/log/capp/server.log*
-rw-r--r-- 1 capp capp 272962507  1. Apr 07:00 /var/log/capp/server.log
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be logrotate will be only on the second run begin to rotate log files. Seems that if no entry for that file is in `/var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status` logrotate will be not rotate the file. So the trick was for me to change in `/var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status` the line

```
"/var/log/capp/server.log" 2019-4-1-7:0:0
```

to

```
"/var/log/capp/server.log" 2019-3-31-7:0:0
```

... and logrotate began to rotate the `server.log` file